# Android WebView: Should shouldInterceptRequest be triggered by XmlHttpRequest

Tags: android, webview, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to integrate a javascript plugin that loads some resources by using *XmlHttpRequest* calls. I want this script to run within a locally loaded page in WebView. As you might have guessed already, *XmlHttpRequest* calls are not allowed for local resources, so I promptly get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///android_asset/resources.html. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

At this point I thought that I could emulate the web server by intercepting the calls and then just loading the file myself, such as:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url) {
        try {
            if (url.contains("resources.html")) { //breakpoint here is not triggering
                return new WebResourceResponse("text/html", "UTF-8", getAssets().open("resources.html"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }
});
```

The problem is that `shouldInterceptRequest` is not being called. The official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) is very brief and doesn't specify what type of requests are intercepted. [This article](http://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/blog/2012/04/23/adventures-with-android-webviews/) sort of implies that the method does intercept *XmlHttpRequest* calls, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Does anyone know if `shouldInterceptRequest` should be called after a *XmlHttpRequest*? If not, is there another way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In API level 16 WebSettings added methods setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs() and setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(). Setting this to true for the webView might solve your problem.

Comment: Does anyone know an alternative for API < 16?

Answer (score 0):

As my testing on this, it seems that only external requests would be intercepted - you can try to modify the local references to be external as "http://foo.com/..." (instead of "file:///android_asset/...").